# True polymorph and the dragon Change Shape feature

Tags: dnd-5e, polymorph, shapeshifting

I cast *true polymorph* on myself and I maintain concentration for 1 hour, so I became an Ancient Brass Dragon, until *true polymorph* is dispelled.
Days / months later, I want to turn back to my original form. Can I use the dragon's Change Shape feature to polymorph into a Lich and cast *dispel magic* on myself?

My doubt is because in the Change Shape definition says "except any class features", so I don't know if Lich spellcasting is a class feature or not. I think not because Lich is a monster and it doesn't have classes, but I prefer to ask.

And what happens if I use Change Shape to polymorph into a Glabrezu, whose spellcasting is innate and has *dispel magic*?

Comment: When you say "shape shift", do you mean the Change Shape feature of the brass dragon, or do you mean the 9th-level spell _shapeshift_? Those are two totally different effects with different rules.

Comment: I mean Change Shape from Ancient Brass Dragon.

Comment: I've edited to avoid any mention of "shapechange" or "shapeshift" for clarity.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### You couldn't change into a lich because a lich isn't humanoid or a beast

The change shape feature of the [Brass dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/ancient-brass-dragon) says (emphasis mine):

> The dragon magically polymorphs into a **humanoid or beast** that has a challenge rating no higher than its own.

A [lich](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/lich) is an undead, not a humanoid or beast. So a brass dragon cannot change shape into a lich. For a similar reason, you can't change into a Glabrezu, since a Glabrezu is a fiend, not a humanoid or beast.

### If there was a different creature, yes, this could work for Innate Spellcasting Only

In the [Dungeon Master's Basic Rules](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/DMBasicRulesV05.pdf) provided by WoTC, the spellcasting trait is defined as follows (emphasis mine):

> A monster with the **Spellcasting class feature** has a
> spellcaster level and spell slots, which it uses to cast its
> spells of 1st level and higher (as explained in the player’s
> D&D basic rules and the Player’s Handbook).

So, based on the language used, it's clear that non-innate spellcasting is distinctly a class feature which is grafted onto other creatures. As such, changing shape into the form of a humanoid with this feature will *not* provide you with their spellcasting ability.

However, Innate Spellcasting states (again, emphasis mine):

> A monster with the innate ability to cast spells has the Innate Spellcasting **special trait**

This confirms that innate spellcasting is not a class feature, but a different kind of special trait. And since this trait is also not a legendary action, the dragon will gain the innate spellcasting of a creature it changes into.

So, if you can find a humanoid or beast to change shape into that can cast *dispel magic* using Innate Spellcasting, then you should be able to change shape and then cast it on yourself, which could dispel the *True Polymorph*. Just keep in mind that the *dispel magic* will require an ability check to dispel the polymorph unless it is cast at 9th level.

Comment: So I searched for humanoids / beasts with innate Dispel Magic and there are none... What a pity...

Comment: Can you even shapeshift into humanoids with new class features or spells using the dragons shapechanging feature?

Comment: @Adam But isn't spellcasting by definition a class feature? I understand that innate spells would be gained, if a humanoid or beast has them, but I don't think the dragon can gain the spellcasting feature (nor any spell in it) of an example NPC.

Comment: @Zso You are correct, though it took me a little more searching to find an official document that confirms it. I'll update the answer now