# Can you use Magic Jar against creatures who have had their creature-type changed into "humanoid"?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic

Here's a question: can you use Magic Jar against creatures who have had their creature-type changed into "humanoid"?

For example, using the 'Mask' option of Nystul's Magic Aura on a dragon to change it's aura into a 'humanoid'; the spell says: "You change the way the target appears to spells and magical effects that detect creature types such as a Paladin's Divine Sense and the Symbol spell."

Symbol is obviously not a Divination spell, and neither is Magic Jar (and Divine Sense isn't even a spell), so presumably they would be tricked in similar fashion - but even if Magic Jar were tricked in this way, would/should the spell continue as normal (with you in the dragon body, for this example)?

Also, True Polymorph can turn our dragon into a humanoid, so could this trick also work?

just to get logistics out of the way, a wish-magic jar could allow for a quick transition and our dragon may already have burned through their legendary resistances and has been feebleminded for maximum effect. BUT let's assume that, with the logistics taken care of, only the magical say-so stands in the way...so, could this trick work?

Answer (score 5):

#### "Mask" won't work

This option explicitly says it works only with "spells and magical effects that detect creature types", and Magic Jar is not one of them.

#### True Polymorph will work

So would Polymorph. It says "The target's game statistics, including mental ability scores, are replaced by the statistics of the chosen beast", and [creature type is the part of game statistics](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138783/).

While controlling the humanoid form, you can try to return it to its dragon form, but [this presumably ends the spell](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133379/) (details are up to the DM).

The Standard Caveat: D&D 5th edition empowers the DM in ways that 3rd, 3.5, and 4th did not. While rule zero has always applied, 5th edition chooses not to explicitly codify many things. If your DM says you can't, you can't.

Comment: Related Q&A on the "can you return to dragon form" bit: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133379/is-a-spell-suppressed-or-removed-when-the-target-temporarily-becomes-invalid

Comment: note that Polymorph does work on e.g. Brass Dragons, as they are not "shapechangers" just because they have a "Change shape" ability; "shapechanger" is a creature subtype from the MM (for example, a Doppelganger is a *Medium monstrosity (shapechanger)*). See also [Can I true polymorph into an Ancient Brass Dragon, and then use its Change Shape ability?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/115351/38495)

Comment: @PixelMaster it's probably true, but worth clarifying

Comment: related question https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/167654/